# Can't get past NodeJs-error after installing azure-cli on bash on ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, apt-get, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview (Build 14316) contains Ubuntu. Using APT-Get I've installed various packages like git and fish.

I've also tried to install the Microsoft Azure command line tools, using:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install -g azure-cli
```

At one point, I even broke my system. Every command I gave returned something like:

```
udev requires devtmpfs support, not started ...fail! invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed. dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd-services: systemd-services depends on udev (>= 175-0ubuntu23); however: Package udev is not configured yet.
```

I could repair that with

```
cat > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
exit 101
EOF
chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

(I found that at https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/143)

However. I do have "azure" in my file path, but when I try to execute it, my system just returns an error:

```
root@localhost ~/n/azure-cli# azure
fs.js:584
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: Unknown system error -25: Unknown system error -25, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/bin/azure'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:431:33)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:421:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
    at node.js:404:3
```

So here my questions:

- What does this error mean?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens when you execute `node`, or more specifically `rlwrap [any command]`? I've been having similar problems and rooted it down to an incompatible `pty` implementation.

Comment: It seems your azure is not well installed. using 'sudo npm install -g azure' to install azure and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

By now, the Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview (Build 14316) contains Ubuntu is marked as beta. For the reason, please see below at https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/.

> it’s marked as beta for a reason: We know that there are some rough edges and that some things will break! Do not expect every Bash script and tool that you run will work perfectly – there will be gaps. But by trying out this feature, you’ll help us figure out what we need to work on in order to greatly improve our reliability, coverage, and reach.

Thanks for your trying. If you have any concern, please continue to post feedbacks or suggest  features etc. via [Windows Command-line UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt/filters/top) portal.

Now I suggest using azure-cli on Windows or Linux (not WSL) for works.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong... this is not in any way a production environment. But if I can in any way do my presentations using bleeding edge technology, I will. That makes it all the more interesting for the audience.

Comment: @realbart It's OK. But now WSL is a beta feature on Windows 10 insider Preview. In the last few days, I tried to test some linux packages on Ubuntu on Windows 10, and I found some packages required linux kernel support not works. Please concern concern the update for WSL and wait patiently for the stable version of WSL feature. Keep your curiosity. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Pan - I still haven't gotten it to work, but I must admit I kind of gave up for a while.

Comment: @realbart Please be patient for the release version of WSL.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 Build 14366.rs1_release.160610-1700 it worked! The commands I ussued:

```
apt-get uninstall npm
apt-get install npm
npm install azure -g
npm install azure-cli
azure
```

It did however get quite a few warninges:

```
npm WARN engine azure-cli@0.10.1: wanted: {"node":">= 4.2.4"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
...
npm WARN engine hawk@3.1.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.32"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
...
npm WARN engine cryptiles@2.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
npm WARN engine hoek@2.16.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
npm WARN engine boom@2.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
...
npm WARN engine galaxy@0.1.12: wanted: {"node":">=0.11.10"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
```

However, finally the azure command line showed its familiar ascii- art:

```
info:             _    _____   _ ___ ___
info:            /_\  |_  / | | | _ \ __|
info:      _ ___/ _ \__/ /| |_| |   / _|___ _ _
info:    (___  /_/ \_\/___|\___/|_|_\___| _____)
info:       (_______ _ _)         _ ______ _)_ _
info:              (______________ _ )   (___ _ _)
info:
info:    Microsoft Azure: Microsoft's Cloud Platform
info:
info:    Tool version 0.10.1
```

In fish on bash on unbuntu on windows 10 :-)